# Making space for Windows partition

Tags: partitioning, windows

So after a year of taking out Windows 8 and turned my laptop into Ubuntu-only, I need to make a Windows partition on it. For some reason, my Ubuntu LiveCD is not working, so I can't use Gparted right now for resizing my Ubuntu partition.

What are other options I have for reducing the size of Ubuntu partition? If I remember well, Windows 7 installer doesn't have a partition manager, so I guess I can't use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to boot something else then the OS you're currently running...

Like a real human doctor, Ubuntu cannot cut itself open and operate on itself... ;-)

If your CD drive is broken, put the Ubuntu LiveCD or [gparted live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) on a USB stick and boot that.

Comment: An upvote would be nice too!  ;-)